# how to sum elements of Map?

Tags: java, arrays

for this code the result it gives me "0":

```
Map<Integer, Long> bwvm=BwProvisionerSimple.getBwConsumed();

         Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

        long sum = 0;
        for (Long val : map.values()){
            sum += val;
        }


        long bwhost=BwProvisioner.getBw();
        Log.print("getBw"+bwhost+"\n");

        if (sum > bwhost){ 

       bwhost=sum;

       }
        Log.printLine("\n new Bw host="+bwhost);
```

Comment: `map` is empty. The sum of zero values is zero. Do you mean to use `bwvm.values()` instead?

Comment: your sum stays 0 because you create a map and fill it with no data

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what you program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your maps: you just initialized them and not inserting values.

```
Map<Integer, Long> bwvm=BwProvisionerSimple.getBwConsumed();
Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others pointed out, your map is empty. But while you're at it, you can check out java 8 reduction. It already has a built in sum() method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html